# Change variable in script thats attached to many gameObjects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

I've been trying to implement this to my Unity 2D game but can't get it to work. While digging through API I've seen this [Object.FindObjectsOfType.html](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) but how do I use it in my case? I have an JS/UnityScript script called "InventoryHandler" which is being added to many gameObjects generated by other scripts, how do I change variable "selectedBlock" (from InventoryHandler) in all gameObjects?

Sorry for no code examples but I don't even know where to start from, any suggestions or examples?

EDIT: code:

```
   //This is my ItemEffect.js
   var itemname = this.gameObject.name;
   this.gameObject.AddComponent(InventoryHandler);
   var itemnamenew = itemname.Replace("_pickup", "");
   selectedBlock = itemnamenew;
   var myScripts : InventoryHandler[] = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(InventoryHandler)) as InventoryHandler[];
   for (var hinge : InventoryHandler in myScripts) {
    hinge.selectedBlock = selectedBlock;
   }

 //This is my InventoryHandler.js
 public var selectedBlock : String;
 function Start () {
      if (gameObject.name.ToString() != "blok_placed")
      {
           selectedBlock = gameObject.GetComponent(ItemEffect).selectedBlock.ToString();
      }

  //This is my BlockSystem.js where I actually read and use selectedBlock var
        var block = new GameObject("blok_placed", typeof(SpriteRenderer), typeof(CircleCollider2D), typeof(BoxCollider2D));
        block.GetComponent(BoxCollider2D).size = Vector2(1,1);
        block.GetComponent(CircleCollider2D).radius = 0.5;
        block.tag = "blok";
        block.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sortingLayerName = "blokovi";
        block.AddComponent("BlockSelecting");
        block.AddComponent("Blok");
        block.AddComponent("InventoryHandler");
        var selectedBlock = block.GetComponent(InventoryHandler).selectedBlock;
```

Comment: How about you start by listing all those instances into some sort of array. and Giving us a copy of the script where you wish to modify the value.

Comment: @MXD Editing variable inside script is not problem, but how do I edit it in all gameObjects? How do I get all those instances into one array?

Comment: @MXD Maybe more suitable question is: how to get all gameObjects that have that exact script attached, and then change their variable?

Comment: but that question you have already answered yourself. Object.FindObjectsOfType

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered your own question. To change the variable in a script, that is spread over several objects. You will first need to get all of these objects. This can be done using the [Object.FindObjectOfType](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) function like you mentioned in the question.

As you do not seem to properly understand how this function works. I will give a small explanation.

The Object.FindObjectsOfType returns a `array` with `Objects` of a `type`. This `type`. For example you can do the following

```
var myScripts: ScriptName[] = FindObjectsOfType(ScriptName) as ScriptName[];
```

Now you have a `Array` of all the scripts you need. Now to process these you will want a `foreach` or a `for`. A good sample of this has already been given in this very document. Which in the documentations case was given with a `HingeJoint`

```
for (var hinge : HingeJoint in hinges) {
        hinge.useSpring = false;
    }
```

Now all you have to do is replace `hinge.useSpring = false;` with some logic to replace the variable. If off course the variable is accessible. But without a script to look through nobody will be able to tell you this.

Comment: I've added this to my code but it does not do what I want. I want it to do things in this order: get all gameObjects with "InventoryHandler" script as component, change variable "selectedBlock" in every one of them.

Comment: @AmarKalabić All you need to do this has been provided in the answer. Unless you are gonna provide the code in question, this will be the best answer you can get.

Comment: I edited my question above with my code from all three scripts.